# SQL Query to check if current row date ranges fall within preceding sequence

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, window, partition

[image: Example table structure]

Example in the attached image.

I'm trying to write a SQL query that checks a given row against the available preceding data.

In this case, the yellow row (6/18/2028) should check against if it's `dtstart` and `dtend` fall within the `min(dtstart)` and `max(dtstart)` of the consecutive preceding rows where `cumulative = 1`.

E.g.

The current `min(dtstart) = 6/1/2018` and `max(dtstart) = 6/30/2018`. However, if the 6/7/2018 row had cumulative = 1, then the `min(dtstart) = 6/8/2018` and `max(dtstart) = 6/30/2018`.

With Pandas, I'd separate our rows and come up with a ranking for each set of continuous values to find the min/max of each set, and compare against the compacted list. Not sure what the best approach is in sql.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Post sample data with expected results to help you better instead of an image.

Comment: Please tag the database you are using.  SQL server, MySQL, . . .